# How to execute specific tests from pycharm terminal? what is the command?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have 5 python tests in pycharm editor. Now i Want to run 1st and 4th test specifically from pycharm terminal. What is the command we have to give to run the 1st and 4th tests?

I have 5 python tests in pycharm editor. Now i Want to run 1st and 4th test specifically from pycharm terminal. What is the command we have to give to run the 1st and 4th tests?

Comment: It would help if you showed code, not least because different test frameworks do things differently.

Comment: Assume that 5 test cases contain the 5 individulal print statments. So we need to execute 2scripts out of 5 scripts from the pycharm terminal. What is the command we need to execute from pycharm terminal.?